# Django не импортирует модель из родительской папки, почему?

Tags: python, django, импорт, python-import

Хочу импортировать модель, но пишет, что SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
Импортирую таким образом:

```
from ..models import Articles
```

Что я делаю не так, и как можно исправить?

Структура папки:

```
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── forms.py
├── __init__.py
├── migrations
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│ 
├── models.py
├── ps
│   └── prs.py
├── __pycache__
│  
├── templates
│   ├── add_news
│   │   └── add_post_new.html
│   └── news
│       ├── post.html
│       └── posts.html
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

Comment: Добавьте дерево каталогов вашего проекта с указанием из какого файла в какой производится импорт.

Comment: Зачем там две точки?

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, вы хотите из директории вашего приложения, файла `views.py` импортировать модель из другого приложения(предположим с названием `app`).

Для этого необходимо указать название приложения и название файла, из которого хотите импортировать:

```
from app.models import MyModel
```

Точка(`from .models import MyModel`) в этом случае указывает на папку текущего приложения, две точки(`from ..models import MyModel`) - на родительскую директорию папки с приложением.

Более подробно можно почитать в [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

Comment: Не работает. Импортировать пытаюсь в prsr.py

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали имя родительского модуля для `models.py` - пусть его имя `parent` и он находится на самой вершине вашей структуры (дерева) - вероятно, имя папки.

T.k. `parent` пока не импортирован, *вы не можете сослаться на него в виде `..`*

Значит, или его сперва импортируйте:

```
import parent.models        # таким образом вы импортируете и parent, и parent.models
```

или используйте форму

```
from parent.models import Articles  # не будет импортироваться ни parent, 
                                    # ни parent.models, а только Articles
```